# window.print() blocks window.open(..)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call window.open(..) and then window.print(). No matter what I do the window.open stuck till the print window is closed.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="PopupPrint();" class="btn btn-primary"> Print </button>

<script>
  function PopupPrint() {
    $.when(Popup()).done(function() {
      window.print();
    });
  }

  function Popup() {
    window.open("https://google.com", "_blank");
  }
</script>
```

Is there a workaround to get this done?

Comment: while you are at it pop 2-3 modals to really break the ux

Comment: why do you need both the popup and the print popup?

Comment: What do you mean with `stuck` what do you expect that the windows you open should _do_ while the print dialog is opened?

Comment: Can't say I've delved too far into the spec for `window.open`, but if any any point along the way it says "queue a task", you might be able to work around it by doing `setTimeout(function(){window.print();},0);`

Comment: @JamesThorpe, setTimeout didn't work.

Comment: Your example here uses `google.com`, in reality, are you in control of the window being opened?  A simple `window.opener.print()` within _that_ window might work for you if so.

Comment: @t.niese, I expect the new tab that gets open to load the google page instead it just hangs till I close the print in current tab.

Comment: have you tried deferring one of the actions?

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I tried that too but it seems print(), alert() etc blocks the child till they are closed.

Comment: If it will block the new window or not is implementation (OS, Browser) dependent. But why is that event relevant to you? You do not call print on the newly opened window, so why do you care that the windows loads while the print dialog is opened?

Comment: Works fine in firefox. Chrome trigger the done event just after opening new tab (before loading the content). As @KarthikeyanSankarababu said print() will block the execution.

Comment: function PopupPrint() {
        $.when(Popup()).done(function () {
         setTimeout(function(){
          window.print();
         }, 500);
        });
    }
this will solve the problem, not exactly because the loading time will be different for each according to their internet speed. replace 500 with most applicable one.

Comment: @AneesSadeek, great! it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine in firefox. Chrome triggering the done event just after opening new tab (before loading the content). That cause print(), and it will block all executions including its child's.

```
function PopupPrint() {
    $.when(Popup()).done(function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.print();
        }, 300);
    });
}
```

this will solve the problem, not exactly because the loading time will be different for each client according to their Internet speed. replace 300 with most applicable one.